# MPAndroidChart: how to set x interval to 1 representing 128 entries

Tags: android, mpandroidchart

I'm asking for help with MPAndroidChart because can't figure it out myself.
I have an ArrayList of more than 40000 Integer values. I need to draw a linechart representing this data. So far I used MPAndroidChart library and managed to draw it  quite nicely where x are my ArrayList indexes and y are the values from the ArrayList. What I want is to have on the x axis interval of 1 which represents a second and each second consists 128 values from ArrayList. The documentation was not clear enought for me to figure it out myself, have done some research on stackoverflow for similar problems but couldn't find anything useful. Can anyone give some advice how I can do it?

Thanks in regards.